# LaTex Error: Environment table undefined

Tags: tables, errors, environments

I have downloaded MikTex. I have installed and loaded "knitr". I saved the file as ".tex" and ".rnw". I keep getting the following error: "LaTex Error: Environment table undefined", along with others. I am able to make pdf documents with other environments such as "article". Isn't "table" a base command, or do I need a package for the "table" environment? What is happening here?

[image: LaTex Errors Image]

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-
mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Thu, Feb 01, 2018 - 9:13:45 PM
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}
{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
emoreg & 270 & 2.043 & 0.817 & 0.000 & 3.000 \\ 
treat & 270 & 0.604 & 0.490 & 0 & 1 \\ 
bullying & 270 & 0.755 & 0.559 & 0.000 & 2.571 \\ 
timetran & 270 & 8.281 & 7.233 & 0 & 90 \\ 
playsup & 270 & 4.459 & 0.619 & 1 & 5 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: the code you show is just a fragment it can not be processed as is: it needs something like `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` at the start and `\end{document}` at the end